# Match [Char] to instance of Read

Tags: haskell, instance

I have a problem with a user-defined data structure and the instance of `Read`

First here is my data structure

```
data Nat = Null | Succ Nat
```

My function for read is defined like this

```
readNatNat :: String -> Nat
readNatNat xs   |first == '(' = readNatNat (tail xs)
                |first == ' ' = readNatNat (tail xs)
                |firstFour == "Succ" = (Succ (readNatNat(drop 4 xs)))
                |firstFour == "Null" = Null
                |b `elem` [0..] = toNatInt(b)
                 where b = (read(xs)::Int)
                    first = head xs
                    firstFour = take 4 xs

toNatInt :: Int -> Nat
toNatInt x | x==0 = Null
       | x<0 = error "Unter Null gibts kein Int 2 Nat"
       | otherwise = Succ(toNatInt(x-1))
```

`readNatNat` as standalone function works as expected, but when I want to use it with instance of `Read` and try to load it i get the following exception

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Int'
Expected type: Int -> ReadS Nat
  Actual type: String -> Nat
In the expression: readNatNat
In an equation for `readsPrec': readsPrec = readNatNat
In the instance declaration for `Read Nat'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Programming the other instances like `Enum`,`Eq`,`Show` etc. was quite straightforward.
I understand that `Read` expects an Int, but i don't know why ;)

I thought `Read` is the opposite of `show` and takes a `String` and parses it into my data structure.

I defined `Show` like this

```
instance Show Nat where
     show (Succ a) = showsRealSucc(Succ a)
     show Null = show "Null"

showsRealSucc :: Nat -> String
showsRealSucc Null = "Null"
showsRealSucc (Succ a) = (if a/= Null then ("Succ ("++showsRealSucc(a)++")") 
                                      else "Succ Null")
```

For your understanding of `Nat`:

Its a representation for natural numbers, so when I type `readNatNat "3"` the output is 
`"(Succ(Succ(Succ Null)))"`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide you `Read` instance.

Comment: If you look at the `Read` class you will see it defines the function `readsPrec :: Int -> String -> [(a, String)]`. Your function obviously does not have this type. The first parameter is a precedence context which is used for more enlightened parsing. The return type must be a list of parses, and the remaining strings. To convert your function to a valid format, you can write `readsPrec _ x = [(readNatNat x, "")]`

Comment: @user2407038 Indeed. Believe it or not, that was all I intended saying in my answer, but I think I got a little carried away!

Comment: The problem with fixing the type error without writing a proper `readsPrec` is you can sometimes have problems reading lists etc. The string at the end should be unused input, and `readsPrec` shouldn't crash like `readNatNat` does on invalid input - it should just return `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

## `readsPrec` takes a precedence parameter

```
readsPrec    :: Int -> ReadS a
type ReadS a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

so

```
readsPrec    :: Int -> String -> [(a,String)]
```

`readsPrec` takes an additional `Int` parameter to indicate the precedence in the surrounding context, so for example if you were reading `Just Null` the surrounding precedence is 10, function application.

In your case, I think you could just use the utility function `readParen :: Bool -> ReadS a -> ReadS a` to handle that:

```
instance Read Nat where
readsPrec prec = readParen prec natReads where
  natReads xs = [(readNatNat xs,"")]
```

## `readsPrec` is supposed to be a mini-parser

1. If the parse fails, you should return `[]`, not cause an error.
2. You should return the remainder of the input in the remaining `String` part
3. (There should be a list of possible parses)

**3. List of successes and

2. Return the remainder:**

This workaround wouldn't be true to how `readsPrec` is supposed to work. The list `[(a,String)]` should consist of possible parses and remainder strings, so that `readsPrec 5 "Null,Null,Succ Null]"` should be `[(Null, ",Null,Succ Null]" ]`. As I've tried to hint there, the remainder of the unconsumed input can be used while parsing a list of values etc.

*Important:*
If you don't do this, you're much more likely to get erroneous results from `read "[Null,Succ Null]"`.

It's rare that there would be more than one possible parse, but for example, if you had decided to show your `Nat` values as `"0+1+1"` you would need to produce for that input, the list `[(Null,"+1+1"), (Succ Null, "+1"), (Succ (Succ Null), "") ]`

This means you should check the number of brackets on your way in and out, so that you can return the appropriate amount in the remainder string: `readsPrec 3 "((Succ (Succ Null)))))"` should be `[(Succ (Succ Null), "))"]`.

**1. Don't cause an error, return []**

If the input isn't a valid Nat, you need to return `[]`. I spot three problem lines:

```
  where b = (read(xs)::Int) -- could crash

  first = head xs  -- could crash

  | x<0 = error "Unter Null gibts kein Int 2 Nat" -- crashes
```

You should really convert these into a check followed with an answer of `[]`.

## Parse recursively

Sadly, I think it means you need to rewrite the parser somewhat. The good news is that it's essentially recursive, and `readParen False` can do most of the work for you. A useful helper function would be

```
fmapPairs :: (a -> b) -> [(a,String)] -> [(a,String)]
fmapPairs f pairs = [(f a,xs) | (a,xs) <- pairs]
```

so that you could `fmapPairs Succ (readParen False)` the remainder when you'd found `"Succ"`. Let me know if you need more than this hint to finish the job (which I think you've shown you're capable of, and is a nice exercise now that you know more about what `readsPrec`).